# Current location popup did not displayed in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am a beginner  in iOS development and **want to fetch user's current location**, I have gone through tutorials to fetch current location.
**When I run app on iPhone device, location authorization pop-up displayed** and after authorize I am able to fetch current location.
Problem which I am facing is **when I run app on simulator, I didn't receive authorization pop-up**. While if i run same code on other's system with simulator, I received auth popup But is doesn't on my system. 
I am using Xcode 8.3.1 to run app. Please help my why auth pop-up doesn't displayed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Simulators don't have permission to fetch Current Location of users due to nonavailability of GPS. Don't you worry about it. If popup appears on a Device then everything is good.

Comment: Thanks Bilawal, but if this is the case than why same code displayed permission popup when running on other system having same OSX and Xcode version.

Comment: Even if it appears on other system for any reason, it doesn't help in anyway. Simulators don't have access to current location. A real device is what really matters in case of location and push notifications.